# Write files inside Hive table hdfs folder and make them available to be queried from Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, orc, hive-metastore

I am using Spark 2.2.1 which has a useful option to specify how many records I want to save in each partition of a file; this feature allows to avoid a repartition before writing a file.
However, it seems this option is usable only with the FileWriter interface and not with the DataFrameWriter one:
in this way the option is ignored

```
df.write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000)
 .insertInto(hive_table)
```

while in this way it works

```
df.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000)
  .mode("overwrite").orc(path_hive_table)
```

so I am directly writing orc files in the HiveMetastore folder of the specified table. The problem is that if I query the Hive table after the insertion, this data is not recognized by Hive.
Do you know if there's a way to write directly partition files inside the hive metastore and make them available also through the Hive table?

Answer (score 1):

Debug steps :

1 . Check the type of file your hive table consumes

```
Show create table table_name
```

and check "STORED AS " ..
For better efficiency saves your output in parquet and on the partition location (you can see that in "LOCATION" in above query) ..If there are any other specific types create file as that type.

2 . If you are saving data in any partition and manually creating the partition folder , avoid that .. Create partition using

```
alter table {table_name} add partition ({partition_column}={value});
```

3 .After creating the output files in spark .. You can reload those and check for "_corrupt_record" (you can print the dataframe and check this)

Comment: I create the files as 'orc', which is what STORED AS tells me; then I try to load into hive with 'alter table add partition' but when I query the data I get a ClassCastException Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable

Comment: Looks like there is data type mismatch between your data and data type of hive column

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this, I also found out that the command 'MSCK REPAIR TABLE' automatically discovers new partitions inside the hive table folder